# Presenting a tabBarController from code removes the navigation bar buttons and title

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I am trying to present a tabBarController using code (not storyboard segue) when the app starts up. If a user is registered, the app should open on the tabBarVC and if a user needs to signup/login, the loginVC is presented. I call this in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`:

```
if currentUser != nil {

    initialVC("tabBarVC")

} else {

    initialVC("loginVC")

}
```

and the initialVC function is:

```
func initialVC(storyboardID: String) {

    let mainStoryboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let initialViewController : UIViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("\(storyboardID)") as UIViewController
    let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: initialViewController)
    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
    self.window?.rootViewController = navController
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

}
```

When the tabBarViewController is presented, the nav bar buttons and titles don't show up. If I segue directly to a VC within the tabBarController, the nav bar shows correctly, but the tab bar isn't presented, as expected. **How can I present the tabBarVC and get the navBars to show up correctly?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to present the `tabBarController` with a `navController`. The code I ended up using that **works**.

In `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`:

```
if currentUser != nil {

    initialVC("tabBarVC")

} else {

    initialVC("loginVC")

}
```

The function:

```
func initialVC(storyboardID: String) {

    let mainStoryboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let initialViewController : UIViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("\(storyboardID)") as UIViewController
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    if storyboardID == "tabBarVC" {

        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
        self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController

    } else {

        let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: initialViewController)
        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
        self.window?.rootViewController = navController

    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check few points:

1) Maybe your settings about navbar are neutral (Top Bar dropdown on the right)

[image]

2) If step no 1 does not work, try to insert navigationItem manually into your viewController:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First, if you are using UITabBarController, you should initialise its property `viewControllers` directly.
 Second, you should not downcast all controller to its base type. 
 Third, possibly you may use such scheme: `Navigation(always root)` - `Initial Controller`, and if there is no login you push `Login View controller`